# How to get firebase list object position?

Tags: java, android, json, firebase-realtime-database

I am using recyclerview with fragment. Following snippet retrieves data from firebase. I have also implemented onClickListener() in my recyclerview adapter and want to start an intent and show a detail profile view. (onClickListener is working as i can get Log msg).

But
How can i pass child key or item id using intent.putExtra(), so that i can start new activity and populate data using that child key or id?

[Firebase structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBUhU.png)

Fragment

```
public class DoctorsFragment extends Fragment {

private List<Doctors> list;
private DoctorsAdapter adapter;
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
private ValueEventListener valueEventListener;

private SearchView searchView = null;
private SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener;

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 * @return A new instance of fragment DoctorsFragment.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static DoctorsFragment newInstance() {
   return new DoctorsFragment();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    getActivity().setTitle(R.string.nav_menu_doctors);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.blank_fragment, container, false);
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    list = new ArrayList<>();

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    adapter = new DoctorsAdapter(getContext(), list);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(2, dpToPixel(10), true));
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.setmOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener);
    asynctask();

    return view;
}
private void asynctask() {
    databaseReference = databaseReference.child("doctors");

    valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String name = snapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                String specialty = snapshot.child("specialty").getValue(String.class);
                String thumbnail = snapshot.child("thumbnail").getValue(String.class);
                Doctors doctor = new Doctors(name, specialty,thumbnail);
                list.add(doctor);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    };
    databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
}

private View.OnClickListener onItemClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = (RecyclerView.ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
        Doctors doctor = list.get(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DoctorProfile.class);

    }
  };
}
```

Doctors class

```
public class Doctors {


private String name;
private String degree;
private String departments;
private String bio;
private String email;
private String specialty;
private String thumbnail;

public Doctors(){} // no-argument constructor

public Doctors(String name, String departments, String bio, String degree, String specialty, String thumbnail, String email) {
    this.name = name;
    this.departments = departments;
    this.bio = bio;
    this.degree = degree;
    this.email = email;
    this.specialty = specialty;
    this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
}

public Doctors(String name, String specialty, String thumbnail) {
    this.name = name;
    this.specialty = specialty;
    this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public String getSpecialty() {
    return specialty;
}
public String getThumbnail() {
    return thumbnail;
}

public String getDegree() {
    return degree;
}

public String getDepartments() {
    return departments;
}

public String getBio() {
    return bio;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
}
```

Adapter

```
public class DoctorsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DoctorsAdapter.DoctorsViewHolder> {
private Context mContext;
private List<Doctors> doctorsList;
private View.OnClickListener mOnItemClickListener;

public DoctorsAdapter(Context mContext, List<Doctors> doctorsList) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.doctorsList = doctorsList;
}

@Override
public DoctorsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.doctors_card, parent, false);
    return new DoctorsViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final DoctorsViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    Doctors doctors = doctorsList.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(doctors.getName());
    holder.specialty.setText(doctors.getSpecialty());
    Log.d("DoctorsAdapter", "spcialty "+ doctors.getSpecialty());
    Glide.with(mContext).load(doctors.getThumbnail()).into(holder.thumbnail);

    holder.overflow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showPopUpMenu(holder.overflow);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return doctorsList.size();
}

public class DoctorsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView title, specialty;
    public ImageView thumbnail, overflow;

    public DoctorsViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        specialty = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.specialty);
        thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        overflow = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.overflow);

        view.setTag(this);
        view.setOnClickListener(mOnItemClickListener);
    }
}
public void setmOnItemClickListener(View.OnClickListener onItemClickListener) {
    mOnItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Doctor POJO add one more attribute, this will be the ID

```
public class Doctors {

private String id;
private String name;
private String degree;
...
```

And update your constructor (also place your setters and getters for id)

```
public Doctors(String id,String name, String specialty, String thumbnail) {
    this.name = name;
    this.specialty = specialty;
    this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
    this.id = id;
}
```

Now, when you fetch the data get the key of the data retrieved, this will be your doctor id

```
valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String name = snapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                String specialty = snapshot.child("specialty").getValue(String.class);
                String thumbnail = snapshot.child("thumbnail").getValue(String.class);
                String id = snapshot.getKey();
                Doctors doctor = new Doctors(id,name, specialty,thumbnail);
                list.add(doctor);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
```

And then in your `onClickListener()` pass the extra of the id in your intent

```
private View.OnClickListener onItemClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = (RecyclerView.ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
        Doctors doctor = list.get(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DoctorProfile.class);
        intent.putExtra("id",doctor.getID();
        startActivity(intent);

    }
  };
```

Comment: I recommend to you to instead of saving your Doctors as 0,1,2,3 and so on, use FirebaseAuth unique IDs or pushKeys

Comment: yeah FirebaseAuth unique ID probably the easiest way, at least for me. i was wondering how custom unique id works.